# how can I reset the robot to the same situations in the beginning of each running?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi, everybody,
I am running the experiments that control a robot to move. But I want to run the same experiments three times. That means I need robot restart with the same situations (same position, same orientation, ...) in the beginning of each running. How can I reset the robot to the same situations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18360/how-can-i-reset-the-robot-to-the-same-situations-in-the-beginning-of-each-running?/) by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-01-25**:
Is anybody else have more idea about how to reset robot with Gazebo plugin? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-01-25**:
I moved your answer to a comment, please don't use answers unless you're answering the question ;) Hope my answer helps

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-25**:
Is anybody knows how to reset the robot situation (position, orientation, and so on) ?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-25**:
@langong, I moved your other comment too. Please don't use the "Answers" space to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From a plugin you could use [Model::Reset()](http://gazebosim.org/api/8.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#a372de693ad40b3f42839c8ec6ac845f4)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-26**:
Thanks! how can I use this function in the plugin? could you give me an example?

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-26**:
by the way, I have to use gazebo 6 because my project is from two years ago, and I could not change it to new gazebo, because it is a huge project.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-26**:
@langong, I suggest this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-27**:
Thanks, I know what your means.